# HTML Resizing Text

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div stay at 500 height.  Text is dynamically inserted into this div.  Different text lengths are inserted.  Right now, my div expands to accomodate the full text.  How can I instead have text shrink so it always fits within the bounds?

Comment: Unless there is a small range of text lengths, I would suggest you stay away from shrinking the text.  It won't take long for it to become small and illegible.  Better to hide the text and then show it on hover or something similar.

Comment: Do you have an example or some code you already have?

Comment: By shrinking, do you mean making the font smaller or cutting some characters from the string?

Comment: Instead of shrinking the text, will a scroll-bar suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use HTML and CSS to dynamically re-size text. You can set the div height to 500px, and either have scroll or hide any extra text.

You can use JavaScript to re-size the text dynamically, but the solution may not be practical if the text length varies widely. Your text will be unreadable if under 10px.

Comment: I could continue to expand the div, but the real problem is I have absolute positioned items in the expandable div, and when it shrinks too small, my absolute items move outside of the container.  Is there a way to have absolute items within a relative container better adjust themselves when the container expands/shrinks?

Comment: @spentiak, can you show us en example. Post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ if you can.